# Shopify Sold Out Message

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to display a sold out message when we set a product's quantity to 0. This bit of liquid code of kinda worked:

```
`{% assign variantQuantity = product.variants | map: 'inventory_quantity' | sort %}
{% if variantQuantity[0] < 1 %}
<strong><p style="color: #B21F1F;">This item is currently sold out.</p></strong>
{% else %}
{% endif %}`
```

The problem is it displays the sold out message when even one size is out of stock and other sizes are not. Is there a way to check and make sure ***all*** sizes are sold out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just check the product.available attribute:

> product.available
>
> Returns true if a product is available for purchase. Returns false if
>   all of the products variants' inventory_quantity values are zero or
>   less, and their inventory_policy is not set to "Allow users to
>   purchase this item, even if it is no longer in stock."

So you can use for example:

```
{% if product.available == false %}
  This item is currently sold out.
{% endif %}
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the multiple checks in the manual?

```
{% if variant.inventory_quantity <= 0 and variant.available and variant.inventory_management != '' %}
```

so example being:

```
{% assign variantQuantity = product.variants | map: 'inventory_quantity' | sort %}
{% if variant.inventory_quantity <= 0 and variant.available and variant.inventory_management != '' %}
<strong><p style="color: #B21F1F;">This item is currently sold out.</p></strong>
{% else %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, it's not picking up the `variant.inventory_quantity <= 0` part . It worked before with the `if variantQuantity[0] < 1 %` but again, it would display even if some the other sizes were in stock.